# Two groups but repeated measures across time only for one

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures

I am confuse to find what model do I use.
I have two group (A, B) with treatment, A has a treatment in t=0 only, but B has treatment in t=0 , 10 and 20.
is-it possible to make one big model (ANOVA; between: group, within: subject and treatment) or do I have to do 2 models: (t.test A t=0 and B t=0, and a Anova to compare B t=0, B t=10 and B t=20)?